# The difference between "spüren" and "fühlen"

Tags: meaning

Could somebody please explain to me, the difference between the verbs "spüren" and "fühlen"? I know they both mean to feel, but do they both have different connotations? My initial feeling was that one is more physical and the other more emotional/mental/non-physical... however I am unable to say which suits which.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"Spüren" is related to sensory perception. Thus you can use it for sentences like

> I can feel the heat. (Ich spüre die Hitze.)
>   I can't feel my legs. (Ich spüre meine Beine nicht.)
>   I can feel the motion of the sea. (Ich spüre den Seegang.)

"Fühlen" can be used in this sense too, so you can take each of the above sentences and replace "spüren" with "fühlen" without changing their meaning. But in addition to that "fühlen" can also refer to moods and emotions, which "spüren" can't:

> I feel attracted to him. (Ich fühle mich zu ihm hingezogen.)
>   I feel good. (I fühle mich gut.)
>   I feel guilty. (Ich fühle mich schuldig.)

You cannot replace "fühlen" with "spüren" in these sentences.

Comment: Yes. It much resembles "sensing" and "feeling".

Comment: Another consideration seems to be that fühlen can be used reflexively (sich fühlen) but spüren cannot. Correct me if I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 11):

**Spüren**

- Physical or mental perception

  > Ich spüre einen Schmerz.
- Craving, jonesing

  > Ich spüre ein Verlangen nach Pommes.
- Instinctive perception

  > Ich spürte, dass er noch etwas im Schilde führte.

*Translations*: to feel, to sense, to notice, to perceive

**Fühlen**

- Physical or mental perception

  > Ich fühle einen erheblichen Druck auf mir liegen.
  >   Ich fühle seinen Puls nicht mehr.
- Sensation

  > Ich fühle mich heute hervorragend.
  >   Ich fühle mich besser.
- Self-estimation

  > Ich fühle mich als Direktor berufen.
  >   Wie fühlst du dich jetzt als Direktor?
- Pride

  > Er fühlte sich als wichtigster Mann auf dem Platz.

*Translations*: to feel, to regard, to consider, to think

Comment: What exactly is a mental perception? How it differs from a sensation? Where do the feelings besides pride/self-esteem (eg anger, happiness, sadness, despair, loneliness) fit in the criterias above?