# "Sich vorkommen" vs "Sich fühlen"

Tags: translation, word-usage, usage, phrase

In welchen Fällen wird *sich vorkommen* anstatt *sich fühlen* verwendet (bzw. bevorzugt)?
Kann man im Kontext "You'll feel __" *vorkommen* benutzen? Also, beispielsweise:

> Du wirst dir da unruhig vorkommen.

Comment: *sich vorkommen* wird fast nur für negative Einschätzungen verwendet: blöd, albern, fehl am Platze etc. "sich fühlen" ist eher neutral: es nimmt gleichermaßen "gut", "schlecht", "alt", "jung" etc.

Comment: Related: [The difference between “spüren” and “fühlen”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5350/the-difference-between-sp%C3%BCren-and-f%C3%BChlen)

Comment: Kannst Du bitte ein Beispiel(-Dialog) oder mehr Kontext für den Satz `"Du wirst dir da unruhig vorkommen"` geben, sofern meine Antwort dir noch nicht geholgen hat (bitte die Frage editieren)?

Comment: @KilianFoth: Er kommt sich stark vor.

Comment: "Sich vorkommen" ist wie man sich selbst sieht, und "sich fühlen" ist welche Gefühle man hat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Unterschied zwischen beiden Phrasen ist sehr subtil, aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche kann man einen Satz nur mit genügend Kontext übersetzen, umgekehrt kann man wohl nur `to feel` verwenden.

Wie Kilian Foth schon sagte, wird `sich vorkommen` typischerweise eher im negativen Kontext und auf sich selbst bezogen verwendet. Man umschreibt die Umstände, in denen man sich befindet, oder leitet eine Erklärung für die Umstände ein.

Eine Aussage mit `sich vorkommen` satt mit `sich fühlen` wird oft verwendet, wenn man nicht so leicht Worte für eine komplexe Situation findet.

Man kann die Aussagen, die sich mit `sich vorkommen` bilden lassen, aber auch mit `sich fühlen` umschreiben. Der Unterschied ist sehr subtil, es kommt dann stark auf mehr Erklärungen und Details an.

Folgende Sätze sich (mit den genannten Unterschieden) gleichwertig:

> Ich komme mir veralbert/verarscht vor. / Ich fühle mich veralbert/verarscht.
> *(Über mich wird subtil gescherzt, ich weiß aber, dass das nicht ernst gemeint ist)*
>
> Ich komme mir missverstanden vor. / Ich fühle mich missverstanden.
> *(Ich habe etwas gesagt, das missverstanden wurde. Ich weiß aber mit ziemlicher Sicherheit, dass es verstanden wurde)*
>
> Ich komme mir fehl am Platz vor. / Ich fühle mich fehl am Platz.
> *(Meine Kollegen sind viel kompetenter als ich, das gibt mir das Gefühl, hier nicht richtig zu sein.)*
>
> Er sagte mir, er kam sich veralbert/verarscht vor. / Er sagte zu mir, er fühlte sich veralbert/verarscht.
> *(Er sagte zu mir: "Ich komme mir veralbert/verarscht vor.")*

Mit `sich fühlen` wird sowohl mit positivem als auch negativem Inhalt verwendet. Einer negativen Aussage betonst Du die Aussage etwas mehr.

> Ich fühle mich gut.
> *(Ich habe gerade meine Schwester wiedergesehen)*
>
> Ich fühle mich krank.
> *(Ich bin erkältet)*
>
> Ich fühle mich nicht ernst genommen.
> *(Auch wenn ich sage 1+1=2, glaubt man mir nicht. Allerdings: Wenn ein Komiker dies nach einem gelungenen Witz sagt, meint er es natürlich komisch ;)*
>
> Er sagte mir, er fühle sich gut.
> *(Er sagte zu mir: "Ich fühle mich gut".)*

---

### Abgrenzungen:

Eine positive Beschreibung mit `sich vorkommen` ist jedoch unüblich:

> <s>Ich komme mir glücklich vor.</s>
> <s>Ich komme mir gut vor.</s>

Grammatikalisch sind die Sätze zwar korrekt, aber ihr Inhalt ist missverständlich oder kann gar falsch (als nicht ernst gemeint) aufgefasst werden.

Der Satz

> Ich komme mir gut vor.
> *(Ich habe gerade, nach vielen Fehlschlägen, ein paar Erfolge gehabt, das muntert mich auf und lässt mich positiv denken.)*

drückt aber eher Unsicherheit über die Aussage aus.

---

### Du sprichst über jemand anderes:

Jetzt wird's verrückt: Wenn Du über jemand anderes mit Hilfe von `vorkommen` sprichst, meinst Du das Gesagte (eher) *nicht wie Du es gesagt hast* und sprichst etwas herablassend mit deinem Gegenüber:

> Du kommst Dir wohl gut vor, hm?
> *(Dein Gegenüber hat dich durchschaut, er hat erkannt, dass Du ihn belogen hast und dich sicher fühlst)*
>
> Du kommst Dir wohl schlau vor, oder?
> *(Dein Gegenüber hat versucht, Dich zu täuschen, Du hast ihn jedoch durchschaut und willst ihn verunsichern.)*

---

### Sonderfälle:

> Ich komme mir vor, wie der größte Glückspilz aller Zeiten.

Hier wird etwas Positives mit `sich vorkommen` beschrieben. Die Person ist definitiv glücklich (sie meint es ernst), aber

- auf Grund der Umstände kann der Gesprächspartner bzw. Leser dies vielleicht nicht glauben oder
- Du drückst damit (im obigen Beispiel) extreme Freude aus

> Arzt: Wie geht es Ihnen?
> Patient: Ich komme mir komisch vor. […]
> *(Der Patient kann sein Befinden nicht genau beschreiben.)*

---

### Im Zweifel:

- drückst Du dich mit `sich fühlen` aus und gibst zusätzliche "Informationen"
- fragst bei Sätzen beider Phrasen genauer nach

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde zu "ich fühle mich ..." greifen, wenn es mir auf meine Gefühlslage ankommt aber zu "ich komme mir ... vor", wenn ich mehr Wert auf den Sachverhalt legen will.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt Fälle, in denen der Sinn beide Konstruktionen zulässt, und Fälle, in denen nur *sich fühlen* sinnvoll ist:

## Beides möglich

**X kommt jemandem Y vor** lässt sich ersetzen mit *jemand hat den Eindruck, als sei Y X*, oder auch mit *jemand hält X für Y*:

> *Das kommt mir sinnlos vor.* → *Ich habe den Eindruck, das ist sinnlos.*
>
> *Die Aufgabe kommt ihm zu schwer vor.* → *Er hält die Aufgabe für zu schwer.*

Dies gilt auch, wenn Objekt und Subjekt des Verbs identisch sind, man kann also *man kommt sich X vor* am besten mit *man hat den Eindruck, man sei X* ersetzen:

> *Ich komme mir vor wie ein Idiot* → *Ich habe den Eindruck, ich sei ein Idiot.* oder auch *Ich habe den Eindruck, ich werde wie ein Idiot behandelt.*
>
> *Ich komme mir verarscht vor* → *Ich habe den Eindruck, ich werde verarscht.*
>
> *Er kommt sich schlau vor.* → *Er hat den Eindruck, er sei schlau.* oder auch *Er hält sich für schlau.*

sowohl *halten für* als auch *den Eindruck haben, dass* drücken eine Distanzierung zum in Rede stehenden Sachverhalt aus.

Daraus ergibt sich, dass *vorkommen* mit der ersten Person in der Regel nur bei negativ bewerteten Sachverhalten verwendet wird -- die Distanzierung besteht hier darin, dass man es nicht wahrhaben will -- und dass bei der Verwendung mit der dritten Person eine kritische, ironische oder gar spöttische Distanzierung transportiert wird:

> *Ich komme mir verarscht vor.* →  *Ich habe den Eindruck, ich werde verarscht* (aber das darf doch nicht wahr sein).
>
> *Er kommt sich schlau vor.* → *Er hält sich für schlau* (aber er ist es nicht).

Bei **fühlen** kann eine Distanzierung zu dem Sachverhalt entstehen, wenn es um Sachverhalte geht, die objektiv bestimmbar wären, hier aber nur mit einem Gefühl erfasst werden, wenn *fühlen* also als minderwertige Erkenntnismethode aufgefasst wird:

> *Ich fühle mich verarscht.* -> *Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob ich verarscht werde.*
>
> *Er fühlt sich erwachsen.*  → *Er denkt er ist erwachsen (aber er ist es nicht).*

In diesen Situationen sind *fühlen* und *sich vorkommen* austauschbar.

## Nur *fühlen*

Es gibt aber Situationen, in denen das Verb *fühlen* keine Distanzierung vom Sachverhalt ausdrücken soll, sondern einen Gemütseindruck schildert, der sich gar nicht objektiv bestimmen lässt:

> *Ich fühle mich gut.*
>
> *Ich fühle mich frei.*

In diesen Fällen kann es nicht gegen *sich vorkommen* ausgetauscht werden, ohne dass der Sinn entstellt wird.